# How to acetylate a thiol group in general?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

I wonder (and have tried to find the answer by searching in synthetic chemistry resources) how do you acetylate thiol (R-SH) groups in general? For example the cysteine-SH group either alone to make S-acetyl-cysteine or, in the glutathione tri-peptide to make S-acetyl-glutathione.

Below I am using SMILES notation, here completely protonated. I am new to the chemistry section of stackexchange, so not sure how y'all draw structural formulas here.

So this is the reaction in general:

```
R-SH + X --> R-S-C(=O)-CH3
```

I am thinking that the best reactant should be acetic anhydride:

```
H3C-C(=O)-O-C(=O)-CH3
```

And so, I suppose the reaction is this:

```
R-SH + H3C-C(=O)-O-C(=O)-CH3 --> R-S-C(=O)-CH3 + H3C-C(=O)-OH
```

Now specifically for cysteine:

```
HOC(=C)-C(NH)-C(H2)-SH
```

We would want:

```
HOC(=C)-C(NH)-C(H2)-SH + H3C-C(=O)-O-C(=O)-CH3 --> HOC(=C)-C(NH)-C(H2)-S-C(=O)-CH3 + H3C-C(=O)-OH
```

However, how would I direct the reaction toward the thiol group and not the amino group? Difference between N-acetyl-cysteine and S-acetyl-cysteine.

Next step of the question is how this would apply to glutathione, when we try to make S-acetyl-glutathione? So glutathione

```
gamma-glutamyl - cysteine - glycine
```

where we have an available amino-group on the glutamyl part:

```
OC(=O)-C(H)(NH2)C(H2)C(H2)C(=O)-N(H)-C(C(H2)SH)C(=O)-N(H)-CC(=O)OH
            ^not here                       ^but here
```

I know people also use catalysts such as simply potassium carbonate or more complex things. Finally, I wonder, how do you get rid of the remaining acetic acid and the potassium carbonate or other catalysts from the reaction to purify the synthesized thio-ester?

I apologize, I have studied medicine not synthetic organic chemistry or pharmaceutical engineering. So, I am asking a lot in one question. I did some research but since I am no longer in academia, I don't have access to journals, such as for [A simple acylation of thiols with anhydrides](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0040403910013328)

Comment: For formatting see: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/86/23561

Comment: Replying to above comment: thanks for the link. Looks like the mhchem format is mostly good for inorganic chemistry, and linear structures. Would be nice to have a SMILES layouter. But anyway, the beauty of SMILES is they can be written free hand and read without special layout.

Comment: You can use the @ to ping members.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! To help you become acquainted with the site, I would just like to suggest if you haven't already, please take a minute to look over the [help center](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help) and [tour page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) to better understand our guidelines and question policies. You will find StackExchange (SE) to be a different kind of Q&A website from the mainstream. To learn more visit [Meta.Chemistry](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/), [Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/), or [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3229)

Comment: I searched Chem Absts. Add acetyl chloride to cysteine in trifluoroacetic acid.  The reference is  J. Am. Chem. Soc., 2014, 136 (31), pp 11050–11056 DOI: 10.1021/ja5048285 although experimental not in paper but probably online.